# Opposite of redundant

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for the opposite of redundant in the following context.

"The danger is that we have redundant work executed, but as also xxxx work"

so in the meaning of "too less", "we are missing something" etc

What is a good phrase here ?

Comment: The opposite of **redundant** wouldn't work well in that sentence, could you expand on what you mean with "but as also ____ work"? Is it that the work is of vital importance? Should the word hint that the work is being neglected?

Comment: You mean to say "but we have also failed to do" certain work. You've done some things more than once but have also omitted some things. Omission is not the opposite of Redundancy, hence my downvote.

Comment: I'm not understanding your example, but in some contexts the opposite of redundancy could be "single point of failure".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure

Comment: The opposite of *redundant* is.

Answer (score 1):

''imperative '' -  as in something of vital importance, crucial.